# saving arrays to an internal device

Tags: java, android, arrays, outputstream

I have searched multiple times for weeks for a simple way to save 4 String[] arrays. I have tried converting them to a Set and saving to SharedPref and it doesn't seem to work out well. I have also come across outputStream, but I haven't found any good examples.

I want to save the following 4 pieces:

```
String[] debtName = new String[10];
String[] debtAmount = new String[10];
String[] debtRate = new String[10];
String[] debtPayment = new String[10];
```

The information is being passed to this activity from another via Intents.

Please provide any simple suggestions for getting these to save internally.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem ... why don't you send these values through intent bundle extras?

Comment: One of the way is to make the array as a comma separated value (`String`). This way, you can save it to `SharedPreferences` as `String`. When you want to use it as array, you can simply `split()` it to `String[]`)

Comment: @antimo - Can you put yours in an example please? Assuming it works, I'll check it for you.

Comment: Any reason you are not using SQLite?

Comment: unfamiliarity... I haven' learned how yet - if you would be willing to throw an answer for it, I'll see how it works with that I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You  can save those arrays  by converting to a String with comma seperated values and save them in the Shared preference.
 Like :

```
private void putToSharedPref(String[] array, String key, Context context) {
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder("");
    for (String i : array) {
        value.append(i + ",");
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    editor.putString(key, value.toString());
    editor.commit();
}

private String[] getFromSharedPreference(String key, Context context) {
    String[] values = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key, "")
            .split(",");
    return values;
}
```

Comment: .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString(key, "")   this portion is throwing an error for "The method getContext() is undefined for for the type DebtList<T>

Comment: Also - how would I call the getFromSharedPreference method?  I've done "getFromSharedPreference(key);" but I'm getting errors on it "null pointer exception"

Comment: instead of getContext() user your context.

Comment: I have one more knowledge question so I can understand a little more of what i'm doing here.... on the getFrom method you have a return values; statement... I understand that return will (for lack of better word) kill the method and return you to where you were prior to it; however, what I don't understand is the variable... what happens to values? If I want to return the debtName[] array, what would I need to do in my onCreate where I'm calling this method?

Comment: in the case of "debtName" . For saving to preference call : putToSharedPref(debtName,"debtName",context). To get the same back, call : getFromSharedPreference("debtName",context).

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(debtName));

JSONSharedPreferences.saveJSONArray(this.getApplicationContext(), "prefName", "prefKey", mJSONArray);
```

Use could save your data as JSON array.

```
public class JSONSharedPreferences {
    private static final String PREFIX = "json";

    public static void saveJSONObject(Context c, String prefName, String key, JSONObject object) {
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, object.toString());
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void saveJSONArray(Context c, String prefName, String key, JSONArray array) {
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, array.toString());
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static JSONObject loadJSONObject(Context c, String prefName, String key) throws JSONException {
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
        return new JSONObject(settings.getString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, "{}"));
    }

    public static JSONArray loadJSONArray(Context c, String prefName, String key) throws JSONException {
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
        return new JSONArray(settings.getString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, "[]"));
    }

    public static void remove(Context c, String prefName, String key) {
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
        if (settings.contains(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key)) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.remove(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I will attempt this tonight and let you know how it works. Thank you for the wonderful response.

Comment: How would I load back into the individual arrays?

Comment: JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
jArray = JSONSharedPreferences.loadJSONArray(this.getApplicationContext(), "prefName", "prefKey");

Comment: String jsonString = jArray.toString();
jsonString.replace("},{", " ,");
String[]array = jsonString.split(" ");

Comment: First time I run it, it returns " [] " the second time I run it it returns " ["[]"] " - any suggestions?

Comment: you haven't saved that array or prefname and prefkey is not the same.